# ¿como conseguir que un proceso lanzado desde un script no muera al terminar el script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

Estoy intentando lanzar un cliente dbus, programado mediante un script Python, desde otro script lanzado mediante una regla udev (el cual se ejecuta como root), y necesito que este cliente dbus se quede en ejecución cuando el script finalice.

El cliente dbus a lanzar es:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Notify
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus()

def msg_handler(*args,**keywords):
   try:
        #show notification to desktop
        Notify.init('Pendrive Reminder')
        notify = Notify.Notification.new('Pendrive Reminder', 'Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown')
        notify.show()
    except:
        pass

bus.add_signal_receiver(handler_function=msg_handler, dbus_interface='org.preminder', path_keyword='path')
Gtk.main()
```

Necesito conseguir que el script lance un cliente dbus por cada usuario existente en el sistema, continúe su ejecución hasta terminar, y finalice; sin matar a los clientes que acaba de lanzar.

Lo estoy intentando de esta forma, usando `nohup`:

```
#Get online users list
user_list=$(who | cut -d " " -f 1)

#Set display
export DISPLAY=":0"

#For each user, launch dbus client
for user in $user_list
do        
    nohup su $user -c '/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py' &
done
```

Pero, al lanzarlo así, el cliente dbus deja bloqueado al script que, una vez terminada su secuencia de instrucciones, se mantiene en ejecución en estado "defunct" (como proceso zombie).

Y, al hacer esto, bloquea también udev, que deja de responder a los siguientes eventos del sistema

¿cómo podría resolverlo?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

He cambiado la librería que uso para el bucle principal del cliente dbus, quitando Gtk y usando GLib

El código queda así:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Notify
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

def msg_handler(*args,**keywords):
    try:
        #show notification to desktop
        Notify.init('Pendrive Reminder')
        notify = Notify.Notification.new('Pendrive Reminder', 'Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown')
        notify.show()
    except:
         pass

bus.add_signal_receiver(handler_function=msg_handler,   dbus_interface='org.preminder', path_keyword='path')
loop.run()
```

Ahora, tras esto, he notado algunos cambios:

- Si lanzo el cliente dbus manualmente desde la terminal, este finaliza cuando hago ctrl+c (el anterior se quedaba ejecutandose y tenía que finalizarlo con la orden `kill`)
- Si lo lanzo desde el script, con

  `nohup su $user -c '/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py' & disown`

  el script termina sus instrucciones, y finaliza unos minutos después (antes no finalizaba nunca).

Ahora lo que necesito es que el script, en vez de finalizar pasados unos minutos después, finalice inmediatamente

Comment: ¿por que me votan negativo?

Comment: A menos que el autor del voto te lo diga (y no tiene obligación de hacerlo) va a ser difícil saberlo. Podría imaginarme que la ausencia de código y un voto apresurado podría ser el motivo, cualquier cosa date una vuelta por [meta] y preguntalo.  Saludos

Comment: Lo que quieres es que el proceso que quede en segundo plano?

Comment: No exactamente. Necesito que el proceso continúe su ejecución cuando el script que lo lanzó termine, pero sin dejar el script zombie, permitiendo que el script finalice

Comment: ¿Cómo ejecutas el script? ¿Qué comandos ejecutas exactamente? Dale a [edit] para añadir los detalles de forma clara (1. ejecuto el comando `bla`, 2. ejecuto el comando `foo`, etc).

Comment: @fedorqui he añadido las aclaraciones que me pedías

Comment: Gtk.main() no debería estar dentro del bloque try:?

Comment: Pues no lo se, no me ha dado por probarlo

Comment: @mzcarlos acabo de probarlo, poniendo Gtk.main() al comienzo del bloque try, y el cliente dbus muere junto al script

Comment: ¿Es posible que tengas el problema en el script python? No tengo ni idea de dbus ni de gtk. ¿Has probado a lanzarlo desde cron a ver si se queda activo o también te da problemas?

Comment: Desde cron no he probado a lanzarlo, pero lo he lanzado desde el emulador de terminal. Allí, aunque el cliente dbus se queda en una espera infinita, si cierro la terminal y lo invoco, el cliente muestra la notificación, lo cual prueba que sigue en ejecución

Comment: Creo que el problema está en esta linea: nohup su $user -c '/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py' &. Prueba a lanzarlo asi: su $user -c '/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py &'. Poniendo el & dentro del comando que pasas a su. No es ni siquiera necesario el nohup. He podido simular el funcionamiento de tu cliente y es correcto (la primera versión, la que tienes en tu pregunta original).

Comment: Ahora el script muere pasados unos minutos, manteniendo el cliente dbus en ejecución. Sin embargo, el cliente dbus bloquea udev, que no admite nuevos eventos hasta que no muere el cliente

Comment: Acabo de probar a lanzar el script manualmente desde la terminal, y veo que termina correctamente al instante, dejando el cliente dbus en ejecución. Pero, al lanzarlo desde udev, tarda varios minutos en terminar ¿será un problema de udev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras hacer varias pruebas, ya he conseguido que el script lance el cliente dbus y finalice, dejando el cliente dbus en ejecución.

Lanzando el script desde terminal veo que el script finaliza instantáneamente, y que el cliente dbus se mantiene en ejecución.

El código del script es este:

```
#Get online users list
user_list=$(who | cut -d " " -f 1)

#Set display
export DISPLAY=":0"

#For each user, launch dbus client
for user in $user_list
do      
   su $user -c '/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py' &
done
```

El código del cliente ha quedado así:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Notify
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

def msg_handler(*args,**keywords):
    try:
        #show notification to desktop
        Notify.init('Pendrive Reminder')
        notify = Notify.Notification.new('Pendrive Reminder', 'Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown')
        notify.show()
    except:
        pass

bus.add_signal_receiver(handler_function=msg_handler,  dbus_interface='org.preminder', path_keyword='path')
loop.run()
```

Comment: Pero al lanzar el script desde udev, el script sigue quedándose zombie unos minutos antes de terminar

Answer (score 2):

Además de nohup, tienes que añadir `& disown` al final del proceso para desconectarlo de la lista de procesos activos del shell que lo lanza.

Ejemplo:

```
proceso & disown
```

Comment: pero ¿eso no matará el proceso?

Comment: Vale, acabo de ponerlo. El comando completo, en mi caso, es:

`nohup su $user -c 'client.py' & disown`

Pero el proceso sigue vinculado a mi script, que se queda colgado al terminar

Comment: No debería, con nohup lo estás desconectando del terminal y con disown de la lista de jobs del shell, por lo que debería ser independiente. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and

Comment: acabo de probarlo y, al poner el `disown`, el script finaliza en esa instrucción y tampoco persiste el cliente

Comment: He añadido mas información @mzcarlos